# What are some nice words to describe a very old age of a person

Tags: word-choice

I wonder what some nice words are to describe a very old age of a person?

I guess directly using the word "(very) old" may be interpreted as being impolite, such as following:

> Are you saying your grandma still has grandparents? They must be very
>   old.

So I am looking for an alternative but nice way to show my surprise on the age.

Comment: This is a hard one, because in most English-using societies youth is valued over old age quite highly. This means that any term that implies an advanced age is going to offend *someone* who doesn't like to think of themselves in that way.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Do you mean that when applying for technical jobs, older people severely suffer from age discrimination? That is really bad.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that specifically, but you could certainly infer it (and I probably wouldn't argue the point). I meant "value" in general.

Comment: Chronologically enhanced.

Comment: How about *senex*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use locutions that are oblique, seeming not to directly state the case, like:

> **advanced in years**

Also, there are words for people who have attained a particular decade:

> **octogenarian**
>
> **nonagenarian**

and for over a hundred

> **centenarian**

Comment: Thanks! Is senior a proper word in the case I gave? I.e. "the grandparents of her grandma are very senior."

Comment: __Senior__ by itself is good for just plain old. Modifying it by _very_ somehow just doesn't sound right, even though it fits the other concerns: 'very old', doesn't sound as impolite/blunt as 'very old'.

Comment: That may not win you any niceness points if they don't know what it means.

Answer (score 5):

would "venerable" work in this context?

Answer (score 3):

Describing someone as "aged" or "elderly" is a relatively neutral way of indicating age, and one description which may even ring positive would be to describe them as being of a "ripe old age".

Answer (score 2):

The person can be called *seasoned* or *advanced in years*.

Answer (score 1):

You might say they are `long in the tooth` which is a slightly nicer way of saying "old".

Alternatively you could talk about long life as a more positive way of referring to old age (although I'm struggling to think of a good example of doing this), or do away with talk about age altogether and say something like `"How amazing to have five generations of your family together at the same time!"`

Comment: Not nice. Originally applied to horses.

Comment: Sometimes being likened to a horse is a good thing, @mickeyf.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the age. No normal person over, say, 80 can be offended by being called old.

Answer (score 0):

The "technical" word I would use is "geriatric."

Another word I would use is "senescent."

Comment: That's not "nice" though.